# Shell Script email output formatting

Tags: email, shell-script, freebsd

I am trying to create a shell script that echo's a bunch of commands and have gotten it to send out emails fairly simply.

```
{
  echo $(hostname)
  echo ""
  echo "Uptime" $(uptime)
  echo ""
  echo "Who is on the server?" $(who)
  echo ""
  echo "Recent logs" $(last)
}| mail -s "Homework Report" myemail@gmail.com
```

The outputs on the emails are all in a single sentence, raw format:

> myhostname.com
>
> Uptime 2:27PM up 15:59, 1 users, load averages: 0.44, 0.55, 0.51
>
> Who is on the server? ec2-user pts/0 Dec 17 14:26
>   (pool-123-45-678-91.state.fios.verizon.net)
>
> Recent logs ec2-user pts/0 Dec 17 14:26 pool-123-45-678-91.state Sun
>   Dec 17 14:26 still logged in pool-123-45-678-91.state Sun Dec 17 05:12
>   - 05:13 (00:01) pool-123-45-678-91.state Sun Dec 17 02:45 - 05:12 (02:26) ec2-user pts/0 pool-123-45-678-91.state Sat Dec 16 22:28 -
>   02:16 (03:47) boot time Sat Dec 16 22:28 shutdown time Sat Dec 16
>   22:27 ec2-user pts/0 pool-123-45-678-91.state Sat Dec 16 21:48 -
>   shutdown (00:38) ec2-user pool-123-45-678-91.state Fri Dec 15 23:45 -
>   23:45 (00:00) ec2-user pts/0 pool-123-45-678-91.state Fri Dec 15 23:23
>   - 23:23 (00:00) ec2-user pts/0 pool-123-45-678-91.state Fri Dec 15 23:23 - 23:23 (00:00) boot time Fri Dec 15 23:23 boot time Fri Dec 15
>   23:21 utx.log begins Fri Dec 15 23:21:59 UTC 2017

What is the best way to format the outputs so that is looks like the outputs on the command lines?

Comment: Could you include **received** message in "raw format"? [Remove `Received:` headers]

Comment: @AnFi Good morning! I have added the raw format message, let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable $last is being echoed as individual words - quote it ("$last") to preserve newlines.

Comment: Excellent! I had set it up like so: echo "Recent logs: " "$(last)" . Now it looks fine! However, I also have this as file I can view through the browser and is wrapped with HTML tags, how would i get it to format within the <body> tags?

Comment: I'm not an expert on HTML, but I think specifying surrounding the text with `<pre> </pre>` tags should do it.

Comment: You're the man!! @varro It looks much better now, tyvm for you help and have a happy holidays and happy new years!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.  If you are satisfied with the answer, please upvote.  And I hope you have a happy holiday season too!